# Postgres: Joining twice on a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I (admitted SQL noob) have three tables in Postgresql that look like this:

**groups**

```
id |  name  | cat_id 
----+--------+--------
  1 | group1 |      1
  3 | group3 |      1
  2 | group2 |      2
  4 | group4 |      2
```

**category**

```
id | name 
----+------
  1 | cat1
  2 | cat2
```

**translation**

```
 id | source |  value  |   type   | res_id 
----+--------+---------+----------+--------
  1 | group1 | Gruppe1 | groups   |      1
  2 | group2 | Gruppe2 | groups   |      2
  3 | group3 | Gruppe3 | groups   |      3
  4 | group4 | Gruppe4 | groups   |      4
  5 | cat1   | Kat1    | category |      1
  6 | cat2   | Kat2    | category |      2
```

The translation table is global to the application and references other tables using the "res_id" and "type" fields. So to get the translation for "group1" I need to use "where res_id = 1 and type = 'groups'.

I need to list the groups in the following format:

category | group | translated category | translated group

This query gets me almost there:

```
select category.name, groups.name, translation.value from groups                                                                                                              
join category on groups.cat_id = category.id
join translation on groups.id = translation.res_id
where type = 'groups';
```

But of course I'm missing the translated category, and have no clue how to get it.

Comment: Just FYI, it's quite handy if you provide sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ form as well, or instead of, psql output. Not really necessary for a simple one like this, just for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about sqlfiddle. Cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
select
  category.name, 
  groups.name, 
  tg.value AS translated_group,
  tc.value AS translated_category
from groups                           
inner join translation tg on (groups.id = tg.res_id AND tg.type = "groups")
inner join category on groups.cat_id = category.id
inner join translation tc on (category.id = tc.res_id AND tc.type = "category");
```

i.e. join `translation` twice, alias each copy, and use a join condition that also filters for the `type` field.

Untested as there's no `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`-form sample data in the question.

None of this is PostgreSQL specific, it's all just standard SQL.

BTW, it's nicer if you don't mix plural and singular forms for table names.

Comment: Awesome, works great. (without the last line, I assume left over from copy & paste). I'm trying to get my head around the last join - should I think of this as a join to a temporary instance of category which is already joined to groups?

Comment: @FrankBrenner Fixed the last line. And no, there's nothing special about a second join of the same table. To understand, try `CREATE TABLE myvalues (id integer, value integer); INSERT INTO myvalues SELECT x, x*2 FROM generate_series(1,3) x`. Then `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM myvalues a CROSS JOIN myvalues b`. That's the cross product of a self-join. Then the `inner join`'s predicate filters it, e.g. `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM myvalues a INNER JOIN myvalues b ON (a.id = b.id)`. The only difference with the above is that there are other tables joined on, it's not a self-join. Experiment with toy tables.

Comment: @FrankBrenner A key thing to understand is that you can *alias* a table when you join on it. At that point, all references to the table must use the alias. If you join a table more than once but use different aliases, it's just like you had two copies of the table with those names.